# Sum of integers closest to a given number

Tags: optimization, integers, integer-partitions, integer-programming, constraints

I have the following problem at hand:
Given an odd number $n > 7$, find a set of non-negative integers $m_7$, $m_8$, ..., $m_{13}$ and $m_{14}$, such that the sum

$m_7\cdot 7 + m_8\cdot 8 + ... + m_{13}\cdot 13 + m_{14}\cdot 14$

comes as close as possible, but does not exceed $n$.
I know that there is not a unique solution, e.g. if $n=33$ there are at least 2 solutions that reach exactly $33$: $m_7 = 1$, $m_{12} = 1$ and $m_{14} = 1$ (everything else $0$) or $m_7 = 3$ and $m_{12} = 1$ (with everything else 0). In such cases I would prefer the solution that has the largest possible values for the coefficients with large subscripts, i.e. $m_{14}$, $m_{13}$, ... .
Is it always guaranteed that there is a solution that can reach $n$ exactly?
Any insights on that problem will be greatly appreciated.

(I guess one can define it as an optimization problem:
Minimize $|n - (m_7\cdot 7 + m_8\cdot 8 + ... + m_{13}\cdot 13 + m_{14}\cdot 14)|$ under the constraint $m_7\cdot 7 + m_8\cdot 8 + ... + m_{13}\cdot 13 + m_{14}\cdot 14 \leq n$.)

Comment: From the usual [Frobenius Coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) computation, any number greater than $7\times 8-7-8=41$ can be written as $7a+8b$ for non-negative $a,b$.  More broadly, since you can clearly get any integer in $\{7, \cdots, 14\}$ you can can get any larger integer just by adding multiples of $7$.

Comment: For the pseudo constraint (and $n≥21$), just take the largest multiple of $14$ which is less than or equal to $n-7$ and then add whichever single term you need.

Comment: Correction:  in my second comment, you might need to add two terms.

Comment: You can omit the absolute value in the objective function, and doing so is equivalent to the knapsack problem of maximizing $\sum_{i=7}^{14} i\cdot m_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=7}^{14} i\cdot m_i \le n$.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing 7 through 14 as summands, I think this can be solved directly without reference to generating functions, the Frobenius problem, the knapsack problem, or linear programming.

Write $n = 14q + r$ with $0 \le r \le 13$.

- If $r=0$, then let $m_{14} = q$ (unspecified coefficients are 0).
- If $1 \le r \le 6$, let $m_{14} = q-1$ and, to take care of the remaining $14+r$, let $m_7 = 1$ and $m_{7+r} = 1$.
- If $r \ge 7$, let $m_{14} = q$ and $m_r = 1$.

This gives you an exact sum of $n$ (for all $n \ge 7$) and maximizes $m_{14}$, the coefficient with the largest subscript.

Comment: I'm not sure about your preference between multiple solutions, though.  For $n = 169= 12\cdot14 + 1$, the method I described gives $m_7 = 1$, $m_8 = 1$, and $m_{14} = 11$.  Would you prefer $m_{13} = 13$?